# Comment traduire une méthode/opération de « drop and swap » (industrie du camionnage) ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

Dans l'industrie du camionnage on a parfois ce qu'on appelle une opération/méthode de « drop and swap/hook », qui consiste généralement à amener une remorque/citerne en un lieu puis à repartir avec une autre (souvent déjà prête).

Comment désigne-t-on cette opération/méthode en français ? Peut-on produire des exemples d'emplois ?

Comment: Il semblerait que le *drop and swap* et le *drop and hook*nt ne décrive pas tout à fait le même aspect du processus (même si à la fin on obtient le même résultat). [*les sociétés de transport routier utilise le processus « drop and hook » (déposer et accrocher). Cette méthode consiste à déposer une semi-remorque vide sur le site d’une société de fret, où elle sera chargée après que le conducteur ait accroché et déplacé une semi-remorque préchargée ou inversement.*](https://www.tip-group.com/fr-be/tip-nouvelles/ou-en-est-avec-la-mise-en-commun-de-semi-remorques).

Comment: [drop and swap (transport par navette)](https://www.group-gts.com/transport-de-conteneurs/) et [ici](https://buro-center.fr/types-de-transport-par-roulage/societe/) description de ce qu'est le « transport par navette ».

Comment: @None Il s'agit du premier cas qui m'intéresse. On y réfère aussi sous le vocable « drop and swap » dans certains cas, certains sites les considérant comme des synonymes. Je m'intéresse plus à l'opération comme telle et en quoi elle consiste en pratique qu'à qualifier les stratégies employées dans l'industrie. Par exemple il y a une procédure, des vérifications à effectuer avant de faire le « drop and hook » concrètement ; c'est ce genre de contexte d'emploi qui m'intéresse.